# Error streaming file on Android 2.x, working on 4.x

Tags: android, media-player, media

I wrote a class that extends Android mediaplayer, the class is the following

```
package it.ccevas.ccevasandroid;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class MyMediaPlayer extends MediaPlayer {

public MyMediaPlayer(){
    super();

    setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            start();
        }
    });

    setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
             if (what == -38){
                 return true;
             }
             return false;
        }
    });
}

public boolean changeSource (String urlfile){
    try{
        reset();
        setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        setDataSource(urlfile);
        prepare();      
        seekTo(0);
     }  catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
     } catch (SecurityException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    start();
    return true;        
}

}
```

It works fine on Android 4.x

But on Android 2.x it works only with files stored on SD and is not working with remote files e.g. "http://www.something.com/myfile.mp3"

Permission on manifest are right:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

This is the `log.cat`:

```
05-03 10:15:06.699: E/MediaPlayer(414): Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
05-03 10:15:06.699: E/MediaPlayer(414): error (-38, 0)
05-03 10:15:06.699: E/MediaPlayer(414): error (1, -2147483648)
05-03 10:15:06.789: E/MediaPlayer(414): Error (-38,0)
05-03 10:15:57.991: E/MediaPlayer(414): Error (1,-2147483648)
```

Comment: Which version of 2.x are you exactly using? And are you testing on a real device or on the emulator?

Comment: 2.3.3 and is emulated on official google emulator
internet browser is working fine on the emulator

Comment: How do you implement this in your class when you need it lets say a Test class.

Comment: MyMediaplayer mp = new MyMediaplayer();
mp.changesource("http://....");

if i call mp.changesource("/etc/sdcard/xxx.mp3") works fine
if i call mp.changesource("http://....") doesn't work

Comment: got the problem
http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2988

Answer (score 0):

you try new url instead of "http://www.something.com/myfile.mp3" because This url not prepare from server.

Comment: used    
 Uri url = Uri.parse(urlfile);
 setDataSource(context, url);
but is not working.